# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network error: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 3

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

i'm just learning react apollo. I found this error difficult to debug. Ofcourse, i have search multiple blog post, Q&A sites and try few of them. No one work. Actually, i want to pass a value to a parameter in GraphQL method Mutation (which its value is an object). Here is my source code

```html
const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: "www.example.com"
});

const ADD_PARTNER = gql`
    mutation LE($input: inputPartner!) { 
        le_addpartner(input: $input) {
            result {
                code
                message
                success
            }
            partnerID
        }
    }
`;

class AddTodo extends React.Component {
    state = {
        name: '',
        nameSlug: '',
        bankLogo: null,
        phoneNumber: '',
        companyProfile: '',
        metaDescription: '',
        metaTitle: '',
        formSchema: ''
    }

    handleValueChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.id]: e.target.value
        })
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <Mutation mutation={ADD_PARTNER}>
                {(le_addpartner, { data }) => (
                    <form
                        onSubmit={e => {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            le_addpartner({ 
                                variables: { 
                                        input: {...this.state}
                                } 
                            })
                        }}
                    >
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
                            <input type="text" className="form-control" id="name" onChange={(e) => this.handleValueChange(e)} />
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="nameSlug">Name Slug</label>
                            <input type="text" className="form-control" id="nameSlug" onChange={(e) => this.handleValueChange(e)} />
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="bankLogo">Bank Logo</label>
                            <input type="text" className="form-control" id="bankLogo" onChange={(e) => this.handleValueChange(e)} />
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="phoneNumber">Phone Number</label>
                            <input type="text" className="form-control" id="phoneNumber" onChange={(e) => this.handleValueChange(e)} />
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="companyProfile">Company Profile</label>
                            <textarea className="form-control" id="companyProfile" rows="3" onChange={(e) => this.handleValueChange(e)}></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="metaDescription">Meta Description</label>
                            <textarea className="form-control" id="metaDescription" rows="3" onChange={(e) => this.handleValueChange(e)}></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="metaTitle">Meta Title</label>
                            <textarea className="form-control" id="metaTitle" rows="3" onChange={(e) => this.handleValueChange(e)}></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="formSchema">Form Schema</label>
                            <textarea className="form-control" id="formSchema" rows="4" onChange={(e) => this.handleValueChange(e)}></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Add Partner</button>
                    </form>
                )}
            </Mutation>
        )
    }
}

const App = () => (
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <div style={{ marginTop: '50px' }}>
      <h2>
          GraphQL Mutation Partner{' '}
          <span aria-labelledby='jsx-a11y/accessible-emoji' role='img'></span>
      </h2>
      <AddTodo />
    </div>
  </ApolloProvider>
);
```

The error i got when submitted the form is

> [Network error]: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 3
>   ApolloError.js:37 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network error:
>   Unexpected token < in JSON at position 3
>       at new ApolloError (ApolloError.js:37)
>       at Object.error (QueryManager.js:212)
>       at notifySubscription (Observable.js:130)
>       at onNotify (Observable.js:161)
>       at SubscriptionObserver.error (Observable.js:220)
>       at Object.error (index.js:55)
>       at notifySubscription (Observable.js:130)
>       at onNotify (Observable.js:161)
>       at SubscriptionObserver.error (Observable.js:220)
>       at httpLink.js:134

Any help would be appreciated :D

Answer (score 1):

Use the Chrome DevTools (other browsers exist) Network tab to determine what the actual response was from the server; this should make the error a lot clearer.

To do so:

1. Open the Chrome DevTools by going to the hamburger menu, "More Tools", "Developer Tools"
2. Reload the page
3. Trigger the network fetch to occur
4. Go to the "Network" tab of the developer tools
5. Select the relevant network request (it should be at/near the bottom; you can filter by XHR to make it more obvious if you like)
6. Go to the "Response" tab to see what the server sent (the "Preview" tab can also be handy as it formats the response in a more readable fashion)

[image: Chrome DevTools network tab with response sub-tab selected]

I'm guessing that the server has sent you back some HTML, which is not the JSON that Apollo was expecting.

If this doesn't make the error clear, post the results of the response to add more information to your question to help others answer.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i got HTML as a response. Is there anything wrong with my GraphQL query ?

Comment: Hard to know without seeing your GraphQL schema. What does the HTML say, perhaps it gives some clues as to the error? Also the URI you pass to the client in your example looks wrong - it has no protocol, for a start, and GraphQL APIs are typically located at a `/graphql` endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

You need to catch the errors for your promisefied mutation. So in your case:

```
le_addpartner({ 
    variables: { 
        input: {...this.state}
    } 
}).catch((res) => {
    const errors = res.graphQLErrors.map((error) => {
        return error.message;
    });
    this.setState({ errors });
});
```